# How to get Rundeck to operate when FIPS mode is enabled

Tags: rundeck

I am trying to get Rundeck community to operate on a RHEL8.7 EC2 with FIPS mode enabled. The Rundeck service will start and say active but I do not get the "Grails application running at http://localhost:4440 in environment: production" when i check logs. When i disable FIPS mode Rundeck will operate as expected. Is there a way to get Rundeck to operate in FIPS mode

I tried disabling FIPS on the underlying host and it worked as expected, however FIPS mode being on the underlying OS is a requirement.

Comment: Hi! Is your OpenJDK 11 configured with FIPS? Take a look: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openjdk/11/html-single/configuring_openjdk_11_on_rhel_with_fips/index

Comment: Yes, everything is good in those files, using 8.7 so according to that it should all of auto configured as well.I am getting alot of "Springframework" errors in the output. So just to add some more to this I can get rundeck run on an AL2 host in fips mode

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Rundeck isn't a FIPS-certified solution, that's reflected in [this](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/7658#issuecomment-1099304312) thread.